# LaTeX beamerで斜体部分のサイズが変更されない

Tags: font, latex

LaTeX beamerを使って学会発表用のポスターを作成しています．
pBIBTeXを使って文献リストを出力するとき，

```
\bibliographystyle{stylefile}
\bibliography{bibfile}
```

の部分を`\begin{small} ... \end{small}`で囲ってサイズを小さくしようとしているのですが，なぜか書名など斜体になる部分だけがもとのサイズのままになってしまいます．
関連すると思われる警告が出ており，

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JT1/mc/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JT1/mc/m/n' instead on input line 13.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `JY1/mc/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using `JY1/mc/m/n' instead on input line 13.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <34.83> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 13.

) [1] (./beamer_file.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

おそらく斜体に関するフォントの設定をする必要があるのだと思われますが，LaTeXのフォント周りのことがわからず手が出ません．
ご助力いただけましたら幸いです．

Comment: その後，.bblファイルを確認し，斜体になっている部分が`{\it ... }`になっていたのを `\textit{ ... }` に変えたところ，斜体部分もサイズ変更を受け付けるようになりました．解決したと考えてよいのでしょうか．

Comment: はじめ2つの警告は「明朝体のイタリックフォントが存在しない」というものです。和字にはイタリック体が存在しないため、通常イタリックフォントが用意されていません。出力された文字が許容できるものであれば、この警告は無視できます。3つ目の警告は「Computer Modern Sans Serif のイタリックフォントで、34.83pt のものが存在しない」というものです。LaTeXのデフォルトでは全てのサイズのフォントが用意されているわけではないためこの警告が出ることがあります。詳しくは TeX Wiki の[このページ](https://texwiki.texjp.org/?LaTeX%20%E3%81%AE%E8%AD%A6%E5%91%8A%E3%83%A1%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8)に解説があります。（ただ、ご質問の部分が私にもよく分かっていないため、とりあえずこの部分についてのみコメントさせていただきます）

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます．リンク先も拝見しました．他にも検索して検討しましたが，よくわからないものの今回はbeamerやLaTeXのフォントの扱いの問題というより，`{\it ... }`と他の環境との兼ね合いの問題のような気がしています．とはいえ勉強になりました．ありがとうございます．

Answer (score 2):

（本当はコメントにするような内容なのですが、スタック・オーバーフローの信用度がまだないので、回答にしています）

`\it`が「フォントのスタイルを変えるコマンド」ではないことが原因だと推測します。一般に`\it`などの二文字コマンドは、オリジナルのTeXで用意されているかなり低レベルの機能で、「別のフォントを使う」ことを指示するためのものです。で、その「別のフォント」として`\small`で指定されるサイズのイタリックフォントがないので、結果として大きなサイズの代替フォントが使われてしまっているのかなと思われます。一方、`\textit`（や`\itshape`）はLaTeX向けに後年になって開発されたフォント選択の仕組みをラップする高級な命令なので、フォントサイズなども周囲に合わせて調整されます。なのでうまくいったのかなと考えられます。（詳しい状況がわからないので、すべて推測ではあります。）

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます．これまで`\it`と`\textit`の何が違うのか考えず，ただ前者が「推奨されない方法」であると言われる（ことがある）のを鵜呑みにしておりました．たいへん勉強になります．